# What is the code to install BiocManager package?

Tags: r, bioconductor, r-graphviz

I needed to install Rgraphgviz package, for which i found this code

```
if (!requireNamespace("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
    install.packages("BiocManager")
BiocManager::install("Rgraphviz", version = "3.8")
```

It seems I need to install BiocManager package as well. Can anyone help me with this? or is there an other way?

Comment: The second line of the code actually installs BioCManager if needed...

Answer (score 0):

`If` statement is checking if you already have [BiocManager package](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=BiocManager) installed, if not then install it. Because we will need this package to install other bioconductor packages.

> BiocManager - A convenient tool to install and update Bioconductor packages.